# Git summary of files -> times changed in last month

Tags: git

How can I print out a list of "file -> times changed in the last month". I can get close with

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: --since '1 month ago' --no-merges | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

But that overly penalizes files on branches where people don't squash them before merging them to master. I only want to count commits in a single merge to master as one change to a file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as what you were probably wanting, but I think something like this should work:

```
for f in $(git log --name-only --pretty=format: --since '1 month ago' | sort | uniq); do
    n=$(git log --first-parent --full-history --oneline --since '1 month ago' -- $f | wc -l)
    if (( $n > 0 )); then
        printf '%8s %s\n' $n $f
    fi
done | sort -n
```

The problem that makes it more complicated is that `--name-only` doesn't show anything for merge commits. But you *want* merge commits, unless everyone working on your repo is using `git merge --squash`, which doesn't create an actual merge commit. If no one is committing directly to master, then the history you want is *only* the merges into master that modified those files.

The first line is similar to what you already have. It gives you all the files that have been modified in the past month. We'll start with the list, then calculate the number of commits later. Note that this is could include changes on other branches where someone changed a file and then changed it back. But that's necessary because the merges don't list any files so we need to look at everything else.

The second `git log` command calculates the number of commits for each file. The [`--first-parent`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---first-parent) option causes it to only follow the first parent of each merge commit. So it only shows changes that *made to* the master branch or changes *merged into* the master branch. The `--full-history` option is used because sometimes commits are not shown in `git log` output if they're determined to be "uninteresting." See the [History Simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) section in the `git log` documentation for a lot more detail.

The `$n > 0` conditional is used because the original list could include changes on other branches where someone changed a file and then changed it back, as I mentioned above.